# Using grep -m to save X amount of lines into new zipped file

Tags: linux

I have a file that has this pattern:

```
@A00479:60:HL5HKDSXX:1:1101:1759:1000 1:N:0:CAGCGTTA
TGAGCCACAGACCCTGGATCCCTCCCTGAGGTCCCATGGGACGGGCAGGCTGGGCATACCTGCAGAGAAGATGTGGCCAGCCACGGCCAGGAACGCATCGGTCACCACAGGCTCAGACTGCAGGGAGATGTGCAGCTGACGCGCCACGTTG
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I'd like to use grep to "pick" the first 100 sequences that have the pattern "@" and save that to a new zipped file

I was trying something like this

```
gzip | grep -m 10 @ test_seq_R1.fasta | cat test_seq_R1.fasta > test_seq_R1_zipped
```

But it is basically returning the same content from the original file test_seq_R1.fasta.

How can I choose the first 100 sequences that initiate with the @ pattern and zip it to a new file using `grep` and `gzip`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you gave the cat command a filename, it's ignoring what's piped to it and just outputting the file. Not sure why you're using cat at all. And gzip should surely be at the end of the process, not the start.

```
grep -m 100 @ test_seq_R1.fasta | gzip >  test_seq_R1_zipped.gz
```

Use '^@' if you want only lines that *start* with @. This will yield all lines with @ in them anywhere.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! I now have a zipped file, but it only shows the lines that contain "@". I'd like to also keep the rest of the content. What I mean is that one sequence starts with "@" and it ends when another "@" shows up. Doing the method you suggested, I only get outputs like this `@A00479:60:HL5HKDSXX:1:1101:1759:1000 1:N:0:CAGCGTTA` when I'd like to get the full sequence as shown in the OP

Comment: I don't understand. Is there anything else in the file besides these sequences? Would it always be the first 100 in the file, or do some not "count"? If it's always just the first 100, you're not really grepping for anything. You're just breaking it up. Are all the sequences four lines long? Then you could just do `head -n 400 test_seq_Ra.fasta`. If not, I'd suggest something like `tr '\n' '\0' < test_seq_R1.fasta | cut -d '@' -f 1-101 | tr '\0' '\n' | gzip > test_seq_R1_zipped.gz`